# Adding stack trace to partial-response

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, error-handling

How to refine the partial-response from JSF with more details, for example stack trace?

I become something like that:

```xml
<partial-response>
    <error>
        <error-name>javax.faces.FacesException</error-name>
        <error-message>java.lang.NullPointerException</error-message>
    </error>
</partial-response>
```

I'd like to include stack trace to be sent on client side, which would make debugging much much easier.

How can I add such information (without recompiling myfaces etc. :)

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 with MyFaces 2.0.2, WebSphere 8.5.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't rely on any part of the page actually being rendered when I encounter a NPE, I forward the request to a specific error page, using omnifaces' [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler). The `errorpage.xhtml` example in the linked showcase also has this line:

```
#{of:printStackTrace(requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception'])}
```

Which points out that you can access several exception related attributes in the request scope.

Comment: But it would require JSF 2.1 EL syntax (giving arguments to bean methods)? Upgrading to MyFaces 2.1 unfortunatelly isn't an option.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. No, `of` is the omniface function namespace, should have mentioned that. You can call that like any other JSTL function.

Comment: Well, OK, it could work, but I don't want (or, I'm not wanted to) make an error page. So I'd thought adding such stack trace to partial-response would be the best way since it would be possible to see for me but it won't be visible for the client (making him less unhappy with short error popup than he would be with long scary stack trace).

Comment: That's where the "can't rely on any part of the page being rendered" part comes in: you just caught a fatal exception. You can't continue in good faith. But as you can see from the [source](https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/source/browse/src/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java?name=1.7), in the exception handler you have full control over the reponse; you can probably wipe up your own handler using that. Still, I think that's a world of pain.